# In C copy data defined in code into a memory location of a char pointer?

Tags: c, memory

So let's say I have code similar to something like this.

```
#define DATA 0x67
char *mydata = malloc(1);
mydata = DATA
```

Line 3 is invalid, of course, but what I am looking of is to take 0x67 and read it into that memory location. It must be obvious, but I don't know what that would be called to ask the question properly.

Comment: `;` is missing at line 3

Comment: regarding: *but what I am looking of is to take 0x67 and read it into that memory location.*  perhaps you meant: `but what I am trying to do is assign the character 0x67 into the memory pointed to by mydata`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to 'derefernce' the pointer

```
#define DATA 0x67
char *mydata = malloc(1);
*mydata = DATA
```

think of it this way.

```
char *mydata
```

says that `*mydata` is a char, you can assign DATA to a char

Comment: fails to add: `#include <stdlib.h>`.  fails to add the missing semicolon on last line. fails to have a function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Dereference the pointer is equivalent to access the first indice of an array (in this case an array of char) which is maybe more easily understandable :

```
#define DATA 0x67
char *mydata = malloc(1);
mydata[0] = DATA
```

If you would have allocated more memory you could access all bytes of this memory this way.

Comment: does not compile!